# please help me in understanding below lua code why the output is like that

Tags: lua, lua-table

```lua
local tab ={};

function tab:myFun(var,va1)
    print(self)  -- output 3  
    print(var,va1) -- output 4, nil
end

tab.myFun(3,4)
```

Comment: Did you read books and all the documentation of [lua](https://lua.org/) ? Did you study its open source code (in C)?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
tab.myFun(3,4)
```

You need to call it with:

```
tab:myFun(3,4)
```